# length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x'

Tags: r, machine-learning, scaling

I'm trying to scale a matrix in R.
I have:

```
maxs<- apply(rawsingle,2,max)
mins<- apply(rawsingle,2,min)
```

and then

```
scaledss<- scale(rawsingle,center=mins,scale = (maxs-mins))
```

I get the error:

> 'Error in scale.default(rawsingle, center = mins, scale = (maxs - mins)) :
>     length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x''

Immediately following the error, I typed:

```
 length(mins)==ncol(rawsingle)
```

and it returned `TRUE`, so I have no idea whats going on.

Has anyone had a similar issue before?

Comment: Can you please `dput` the `rawsingle` dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that some elements in 'rawsingle' were character strings due to an error in loading it.

Answer (score 0):

All the variables needs to be of type `numeric`:

`dades[2:13] <- lapply(dades[2:13], as.numeric)`